# @Font-Face Custom fonts not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, font-face

I'm having trouble getting a custom, non-websafe font to work in Firefox. I have it working in Chrome, Opera and Safari using the following code:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Antic+Slab);

@font-face {
font-family: 'BadgerFont';
src: url('http://www.vectorthatfox.co.uk/badgerandkingdom/fonts/oratorstd-webfont.eot');
src: url('http://www.vectorthatfox.co.uk/badgerandkingdom/fonts/oratorstd-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('http://www.vectorthatfox.co.uk/badgerandkingdom/fonts/oratorstd-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://www.vectorthatfox.co.uk/badgerandkingdom/fonts/oratorstd-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('http://www.vectorthatfox.co.uk/badgerandkingdom/fonts/oratorstd-webfont.svg#orator_stdregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body{
font-family: BadgerFont, 'Antic Slab', Serif;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

What am i missing here?
[Heres a link](http://badgerandkingdom.bigcartel.com/) to the site incase you want to see for yourself.

Comment: Deryck, are you sure that you are seeing the @font-face font rather than the google apis font?

Comment: This is truly mind-boggling to me lol works in Chrome, other font works in FF but this BadgerFont/OratorStd just refuses to load in FF, no matter what order I put it in, what other font declarations i disable, what `@imports` I remove, it stays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Firefox will only accept relative links. Firefox (which supports `@font-face` from v3.5) does not allow cross-domain fonts by default. This means the font must be served up from the same domain (and sub-domain) unless you can add an “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” header to the font.

Or, just load the font some other way (locally or with a CDN)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to use your developer tools in Firefox. Fifth console message is this:

`[08:28:41.886] Unrecognized at-rule or error parsing at-rule '@import'. @ http://cdn.bigcartel.com/theme_stylesheets/19013562/2771282761/theme.css:474`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import):

> The @import CSS at-rule allows to import style rules from other style
>   sheets. These rules must precede all other types of rules, except
>   @charset rules; as it is not a nested statement, it cannot be used
>   inside conditional group at-rules.

**EDIT**

Please look in your console, it gives you all the answers

```
[11:00:17.697] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "BadgerFont" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://www.vectorthatfox.co.uk/badgerandkingdom/fonts/oratorstd-webfont.woff @ http://cdn.bigcartel.com/theme_stylesheets/19013568/2771283940/theme.css
```

As the message says, Firefox will not allow you to embed cross-domain fonts. If you want to use that font, then download them from that website, if you are allowed, and upload them to your own domain and link to them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Thats got the GoogleFont imported font working, but my @font-face font 'BadgerFont' is still not working!